# How to Export MongoDB collection in JSON format into local system?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How to export mongodb collection to local memory in JSON fromat

I am using

mongoexport -d  -c  --jsonArray -o nametosave

(or)

mongoexport -d   -c  --out name.json

in both cases I am getting as JSON like:

`{"_id":{"$oid":"xxxxxxxxxxx"}`,"geo":["13.0156289","77.6321339"],"locality":"Kacharakanahalli","pincode":560084,"state":"Karnataka","created_at":{"$date":"2018-08-10T08:19:17.086Z"},"updated_at":{"$date":"2018-08-10T08:19:17.086Z"},"__v":0}
{"_id":{"$oid":"xxxxxxxxx"},"geo":["13.0280047","77.6399711"],"locality":"Kalyanagar","pincode":560043,"state":"Karnataka","created_at":{"$date":"2018-08-10T08:19:17.086Z"},"updated_at":{"$date":"2018-08-10T08:19:17.086Z"},"__v":0}

I need to get JSON without $oid and $date, I need directly like this

```
{"_id":"xxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

to match this requirement what process I need to use while exporting the collection

Comment: You could just transform the data.

Comment: As per MongoDB documentation `mongoexport` is using [strict mode representation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) which is including `$oid` (`ObjectID`) to preserve type information. Probably you need to either switch ID type (which is probably impossible in your case) or use external program to transform your JSON after export.